# where does linux look to find binaries when we write them to console

Tags: console, application-launch

I wonder where does linux, particularly Ubuntu or Debian, look to find binaries when we write to console to run them?
For example when I write `firef` and hit the tab it completes to `firefox`. I know it looks it from **/usr/bin** but there may be another places.

My main problem is that I am working on a debian machine where I don't have a root access. I have only write access to my home directory and I want to add a stand-alone application(let's say eclipse) and then run it by just writing `eclipse` to the console.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It checks the directories listed in `$PATH`.

Comment: To add a bit to this answer, it checks directories listed in $PATH as they are listed, so if multiple directories have files with same name, executable in the first directory listed will be used.

Comment: ... plus, of course, [hash table lookasides](http://gnu.org./software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-hash-117) and [programmable completion](http://gnu.org./software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion) have an effect as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the directory of eclipse to your `$PATH` :

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/myuser/eclipsedir/bindir
```

You will be able to launch all programs in this directory by just typing its name.

If you want to manage it a different way, you can also create a `~/bin` directory in your home folder where you will put symbolic links to programs you want in direct access.

```
ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME
```

`TARGET` is the Eclipse bin path, `LINK_NAME` the command you want to run for launching Eclipse.

Comment: If eclipse has any shared libraries that it needs (or dependencies on other things that aren't installed so you have to install in your homedir) you may have to also adjust $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the shared library directories.